# How to update Qt Maintenance Tool

Tags: qt

I am using Qt 5.10.1 on windows 10, when I was trying to add qt repositories using the Maintenance Tool, specifically I need to add the Qt Charts module. Then it gave me this error:

> Your Maintenance Tool appears to be older than 3.0.2. Please update it first to get access to new Qt packages.

Why would this happen? I am currently using the latest Qt version, and I did not find a way to update the Maintenance Tool. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I just encountered this issue.

Strangely enough, if you hit the quit button when this happens, the tool moves onto the next page, and *then* prompts you if you want to exit. If you cancel exiting, it then allows you to update the maintenance tool (the current version is apparently 3.0.4).

So basically, hit "quit", cancel the exiting, and it then updates itself.

Comment: Wow, that's weird. At least it works if you select "Update components" on the Setup - Qt page. If you select "Add or remove components", it seems to be stuck on the 1st page, and the exploit doesn't work anymore even if you select "Update components" afterward.

Comment: thx! even after I updated the MaintenanceTool to 3.1.1, it keeps complaining about an old version, but using your trick, I can access all functions (add/remove/update)

Comment: okay, i changed my username and that seems to cause all kinds of trouble with the qt install, so that's probably why the MaintenanceTool is complaining too

Comment: apparently, not the username thingy, because i tried it on a windows box without changing my username and it yielded exactly the same problem